# Switching divs based on clicked link - plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some non-jquery solution for switching divs with clicked link and external addEventListener.
I basically did my best to achieve it, but now I am lost.
Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

My HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="switch-button" data-id="switch1">Div1</a>
<a href="#" class="switch-button" data-id="switch2">Div2</a>
<a href="#" class="switch-button" data-id="switch3">Div3</a>
<a href="#" class="switch-button" data-id="switch4">Div4</a>
<div class="switch" id="switch1" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: blue;"></div>
<div class="switch" id="switch2" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: red; display: none;"></div>
<div class="switch" id="switch3" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: green; display: none;"></div>
<div class="switch" id="switch4" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: yellow; display: none;"></div>
```

I am basically trying to convert this

```
$('.news-toggle').click(function (e) {
    var thisDataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.news-toggle-box').fadeOut(300);
    $('#' + thisDataId).delay(300).fadeIn(300);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

to something like this

```
window.onload = function toggleDiv(){
            var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('switch-button');
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('switch');

            for(i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
                buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                    for(j=0; j<divs.length; j++){
                        divs[j].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    for(i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
                        var dataID = buttons[i].getAttribute('data-id');
                        document.getElementById(dataID).style.display = 'block';
                    }

                })
            }
        }
```

but it does not work properly.

Thanks a lot for your advices ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try translating the jQuery and also use `class`es for hiding and showing `<div>`:

```js
var sb = document.querySelectorAll('.switch-button');
var ntb = document.querySelectorAll('.switch');
for (i = 0; i < ntb.length; i++)
  ntb[i].classList.add("hidden");
for (i = 0; i < sb.length; i++)
  sb[i].onclick = function () {
    var thisDataId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    (function (thisDataId) {
      var ntb = document.querySelectorAll('.switch');
      for (i = 0; i < ntb.length; i++)
        ntb[i].classList.add("hidden");
      document.querySelector("#" + thisDataId).classList.remove("hidden");
    })(thisDataId);
    return false;
  }
```

```css
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="switch-button" data-id="switch1">Div1</a>
<a href="#" class="switch-button" data-id="switch2">Div2</a>
<a href="#" class="switch-button" data-id="switch3">Div3</a>
<a href="#" class="switch-button" data-id="switch4">Div4</a>
<div class="switch" id="switch1" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: blue;"></div>
<div class="switch" id="switch2" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: red;"></div>
<div class="switch" id="switch3" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: green;"></div>
<div class="switch" id="switch4" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: yellow;"></div>
```

> **Note:** I had a hard time because there was no class with the name: `.news-toggle` and `.news-toggle-box`. God!

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the Jquery you've mentioned,I believe your trying to hide the news toggle box and show the respective div which match the clicked data-id.Change the code to

```
window.onload = function toggleDiv(){
            var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('switch-button');
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('switch');

            for(i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
                buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
                    for(j=0; j<divs.length; j++){
                        divs[j].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    //Get the data-id of the current div
                    var data_id=event.target.getAttribute("data-id");
                    var currentDiv=document.getElementById(data_id); 
                    currentDiv.style.display="block";
                    //Do whatever you want with your news toggle
                })
            }
        }`
```